# Is there a way to automate sending a Google form every Monday?

Tags: windows, google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to send a Google Form to the same email address every Monday. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Use a time driven trigger:  [Google Documentation - Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Create an excel with a list of email addresses.
2. Create a script that sends the email with link to the form.
3. Set a time driven trigger; nowadays you can pick which day and between what hours